# gu No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, docker, micronaut, graalvm

I'm building a docker image out of a micronaut application.

But whenever I run the docker build command

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t micronaut .
```

I get this error

```
/bin/sh: /bin/gu: No such file or directory
```

Here's the content of my docker file anyway:

```
FROM oracle/graalvm-ce:20.0.0-java11 as graalvm
RUN $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu install native-image

COPY . /home/app/micronautguide
WORKDIR /home/app/micronautguide

RUN $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/native-image --no-server -cp build/libs/complete-*-all.jar

FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
RUN apk update && apk add libstdc++
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=graalvm /home/app/micronautguide/micronautguide /micronautguide/micronautguide
ENTRYPOINT ["/micronautguide/micronautguide", "-Xmx68m"]
```

Though by running `gu` command from the terminal works.

Comment: /bin/gu has to exist in the docker image. RUN statement will run in the container built up to that point. Make sure /bin/gu exists before you RUN it.

Answer (score 1):

Your context does not contain `RUN $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu` . What is `$GRAAL_VM_HOME`? Whatever this variable is, it is set as null. Also, `$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu` needs to be part of docker image.

Answer (score 0):

`$GRAALVM_HOME` does not exists in the oracle/graalvm-ce:20.0.0-java11 container. Thus, make suer to specify the right path. In this case it is `/bin/gu`

I think `$GRAALVM_HOME` is a variable you use in the local machine and `gu tool` is already installed and available at /bin in the docker image. So I have kept the `$GRAALVM_HOME` unchanged in the second build stage.

So, the Dockerfile should be like below,

```py
FROM oracle/graalvm-ce:20.0.0-java11 as graalvm
RUN /bin/gu install native-image

COPY . /home/app/micronautguide
WORKDIR /home/app/micronautguide

RUN /bin/native-image --no-server -cp build/libs/complete-*-all.jar

FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
RUN apk update && apk add libstdc++
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=graalvm /home/app/micronautguide/micronautguide /micronautguide/micronautguide
ENTRYPOINT ["/micronautguide/micronautguide", "-Xmx68m"]
```